# How do I print the percent sign(%) in C?

Tags: c, printf, percentage

Why doesn't this program print the `%` sign?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
     printf("%");
     getch();
}
```

Comment: So did you read the documentation? What did it say about the percent sign?

Comment: This question can be easily answered through Google. The OP could have used his logic, ie (`'//`) is the character constant for `/` and applied this. Isn't there also a man page on `printf`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say that `'\\'` is the character constant for `\ `? The character constant for `/` is `'/'`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your problem is that you have to change:

```
printf("%");
```

to

```
printf("%%");
```

Or you could use ASCII  code and write:

```
printf("%c", 37);
```

:)

Comment: C doesn't require ASCII. `printf("%c", 37);` is not portable.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes but I like the answer because he given an extra trick!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I didn't say I didn't like the answer, it's a good answer. I only pointed out that the aforementioned snippet is not portable.

Comment: @H2CO3 yup i know...I just like to say you that I might simply post `printf("%%");` answer but not using ascii. You commented here when I was editing this answer. :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Of course. No offense :)

Comment: Why not use `'%'` instead of `37`?

Answer (score 28):

There's no explanation in this topic why to print a percentage sign. One must type `%%` and not for example an escape character with percentage - `\%`.

From [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 12.6](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/printfpercent.html):

> The reason it's tricky to print % signs with printf is that % is
> essentially printf's escape character. Whenever printf sees a %, it
> expects it to be followed by a character telling it what to do next.
> The two-character sequence %% is defined to print a single %.
>
> To understand why % can't work, remember that the backslash \ is the
> compiler's escape character, and controls how the compiler interprets
> source code characters at compile time. In this case, however, we want
> to control how printf interprets its format string at run-time. As far
> as the compiler is concerned, the escape sequence % is undefined, and
> probably results in a single % character. It would be unlikely for
> both the \ and the % to make it through to printf, even if printf were
> prepared to treat the \ specially.

So the reason why one must type `printf("%%");` to print a single `%` is that's what is defined in the printf function. `%` is an escape character of printf's, and `\` of the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for offering the reason.

Answer (score 8):

Use `"%%"`.  The [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/) describes this requirement:

> `%`       A '%' is written.  No argument is converted.  The complete conversion specification is '`%%`'.

Answer (score 3):

Try printing out this way

```
printf("%%");
```

Comment: This answer could be more useful than that. It doesn't give any reference enabling the readers to learn about their mistakes.